# Difference between tar -tf vs tar -tzf

Tags: tar, compression

I am trying to list the contents of a tar file. I see that by combining `-t` and `-f` I can do so. It seems to work even for compressed archives.

The combination of `-z` in addition with `-tf` also seems to give the same result. Does this mean that `-z` in this context has no effect or the effect is there but not observable.

I am a noob. So pardon mistakes if any in my question.

Comment: **tar**, ref. Sergey Poznyakoff, **2004**-12-20 : "Compressed archives are recognised automatically, it is no longer
necessary to specify -Z, -z, or -j options to read them. 
( Thus, you can now run `tar tf archive.tar.gz'.)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1168/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct that `-tf` and `-tzf` are the same for your file.

Modern versions of `tar` can automatically *guess* the type of compression of a compressed file. So, if it's a `gzip` file, it does not matter whether you specify the `-z` part or not.

For the same reason, you don't have to specify the `j` part in `-tjf` if it's a bzip2 compressed file.